# Removing values from dict in python

Tags: python, logic

This code:

```
a = {'sd':{},'sdd':'','sadfas':None,'sadfa':'dsf'}
a = dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v is not '' or v != {} or v is not None)
print a
```

prints:

```
{'sdd': '', 'sadfas': None, 'sadfa': 'dsf', 'sd': {}}
```

However, it does not remove all the type of values from dict which i need to remove. Why is that ?

These values are removed if i do:

```
a = {'sd':{},'sdd':'','sadfas':None,'sadfa':'dsf'}

a=dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v is not '')
a=dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v is not None)
a=dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v)

print a
```

This prints:

```
{'sadfa': 'dsf'}
```

which is what we want, but i have to iterate over dictionary 3 times in order to achieve. Can you suggest a more optimised way.

Comment: You need `and`, not `or`.

Comment: I think you mean to use AND between your arguments.  "if v is not '' or v != {}" is always True!  But then, "if v", will return False for '' and {}, so the most efficient is your last one in the second example.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `v is not ''` should be `v != ''`.  You should always use `==` and `!=` to compare two values because `is` and `is not` are for comparing the *identities* of two objects.
2. You need to use `and` instead of `or`.  Otherwise, this condition:

   ```
   v != '' or v != {} or v is not None
   ```

   will always be `True` because `v` will always be either not equal to `''` or not equal to `{}`.

Below is a fixed version of your code:

```
>>> a = {'sd':{},'sdd':'','sadfas':None,'sadfa':'dsf'}
>>> a = dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v != '' and v != {} and v is not None)
>>> a
{'sadfa': 'dsf'}
>>>
```

---

However, we can simplify this further:

```
>>> a = {'sd':{},'sdd':'','sadfas':None,'sadfa':'dsf'}
>>> a = dict((k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems() if v)
>>> a
{'sadfa': 'dsf'}
>>>
```

This solution works because `''`, `{}`, and `None` all evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
empties = ('', {}, None)
{k:v for k,v in a.items() if v not in empties}
# for your input this would work too, 
# as all 'emtpies' evaluate to False:
{k:v for k,v in a.items() if v}

# or if you want to remove in-place:
for key in a.keys():
    # if a[key] in empties:
    if not a[key]:
        del a[key]
```

Above works in python 2.7+, if you need solution for earlier version, you can use `dict()` and generator comprehension:

```
dict((k,v) for (k,v) in a.items() if v)
# or
dict(element for element in a.items() if element[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
dict([x for x in d.items() if x[1]])
```

becase of `''`, `None`, `{}` stand for the same thing `False`, when they are used in `if`.